# Unable to locate sign!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have been having a problem recently where I get an error message and for some reason a Clone of me appears. The error message reads: "Unable to locate sign at [coordinates]"

[image]

It's very interesting, because when I kill it, spawns duplicate items. This is very annoying as sometimes I get stuck in Nether portals and due to the 1.8 bug I am stuck in an infinite loop of portal spawning and I disconnect because of it. It is extremely annoying and I am not running any mods.

This only happens when I login.

Any solutions?

Comment: Are you running a map?

Comment: No we have a server that is running this I already contacted my Admin about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The clone issue is a known issue that will be [fixed](https://twitter.com/Dinnerbone/status/529041733028679681) in the next pre-release. Unfortunately, I don't have a solution other than 'wait for the next update'.

Comment: This bug was not fixed in any pre-release and is still unresolved [MC-3564](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-3564), also, the tweet you have linked to refers to another bug altogether.

Comment: The tweet refers to the player cloning (item duplication bug) which the OP is asking for and it was indeed fixed. Although the question title says "Unable to locate sign!", the question body makes it clear what the question is about.